# Liferay + AspectJ not working after version upgrade

Tags: java, logging, liferay, aspectj

in our project under Liferay 6.1 we have 1 aspect class - TimedMethod, which we add to the methods that we want to record time of execution. We have a jar org.aspect.runtime_1.7.3 and it is ok on Liferay 6.1. After the upgrade to 6.2, there were many issues that we had to solve. One of them is the aspects that do not work. We have only one in the whole project.
Here is the aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>
 <weaver>
      <include within="com.*"/>
 </weaver>
 <aspects>
      <aspect name="com.dzi.portal.timedMethod.TimedMethodLogger"/>
 </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

The code of the aspect is

```
@Aspect
public class TimedMethodLogger {
    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerUtil.getLoggerForUser();  
    private static int level = 0;

    @Around(value = "execution(@TimedMethod * *(..))")
    public Object logMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        String tabs = writeTab(level);

        LOGGER.info((level == 0 ? "First called method: " : tabs + "Level:" +     level + " Called method: ") + pjp.getSignature().toLongString());

        Date start = new Date();
        level++;
        Object methodResult = pjp.proceed();
        level--;
        Date end = new Date();

        Double executionTime = (double) (end.getTime() - start.getTime());
        if (executionTime != 0) {
            executionTime /= 1000;
        }

        String message = tabs + "End of method: " +     pjp.getSignature().toShortString() + " -> Time of execution: " + executionTime +     " seconds"
            + (level == 0 ? LoggerUtil.newLine + LoggerUtil.dashSplit : "");
    executionTime);

    LOGGER.info(message);

    return methodResult;
}
```

The TimedMethod is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface TimedMethod {
}
```

and we put the @TimedMethod before the method that we want to have log for. The server does not throw exceptions. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Obvious things first: Did you check the Library Versions?

Comment: we just added org.aspect.runtime_1.8.4 or so and it is ok now... I thought it should be backward compatible :/

Comment: Yeah, with every update they are changing some libs. You always have to check this first if you plan to migrate to a new version. Here is a list of the libs liferay uses and their corresponding versions: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/lib/versions.xml